# MSI B150M Pro-VD mobo hangs on suspend in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, sleep

I can't restore my *Linux Mint 18.3*, (Kernel *v4.13.0-32-generic x86_64* 
 running on a [*MSI B150M PRO-VD (MS-7996) v1.0*](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B150M-PRO-VD.html) mobo), from sleep mode.

Last messages on screen (at same second):

```
[19.....] Disabling non-boot CPUs
[19.....] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[19.....] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[19.....] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
```

After those messages, system freezes: keyboard (even "*magic sysrq*" and *numlock* indicator) does not work, no any disk activity or more messages on terminal. Only one solution works - hard reset.

Comment: What is your hardware? How are you entering sleep?

Comment: This happened with me too, the solution was to press the power button once, like when you power on the machine, That will probably sleep the computer. Now press the power button again and you will be straight to the lock screen. This is like a hibernation feature.

Comment: @Kusalananda https://gist.github.com/anonymous/39c6ec06b2a3c44065208ce1ad1a86eb -  my system. I use Sleep mode button in Shutdown menu, or same effect with `systemctl hibernate`.

Comment: @RajneeshGadge for me it just preforms shutdown, not hibreneration.

Answer (score 2):

You should upgrade the BIOS of your motherboard.

> Machine:   Mobo: MSI model: B150M PRO-VD (MS-7996) v: 1.0
>
> Bios: American Megatrends v: 1.60 date: 03/16/2016

Since that time, MSI did provide [6 new versions of the BIOS](https://fr.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B150M-PRO-VD). As the sleep mode is quite impacted by BIOS quality, I hope MSI did correct your problem with new versions of the BIOS.

Greetings.

Comment: Thank you, but after updating to lastest BIOS nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

With problems like this, try a different kernel, or failing that, when the *amd64* kernels won't work, try a *32-bit* version of your Linux distro.

1. If one is too lazy to muddle through the usual kernel install
   methods, there's an [allegedly less painful kernel installer
   `ukuu`](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/ukuu-kernel-upgrade-utility.html), which in *Ubunutu*-based distros like *Mint* can be had
   like so:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install ukuu
   ```

   Then run:

   ```
   sudo ukuu-gtk
   ```

   ...and a kernel picking GUI will appear.  Test some, maybe the
   latest, or if that fails, an older one.
2. If none of that helps, sometimes the *i386* or *i686* suspend code
   works better than the *amd64* stuff, (or at least it does on some
   laptops).  On your system that would be [Linux Mint 18.3 "Sylvia" -
   Cinnamon (32-bit)](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=245).  This is more work than a kernel change, but
   it can probably be tested first from the *bootCD* or *USB* drive,
   without going through the trouble of installing it.